# mysql storing text as question marks (flask server)

Tags: mysql, flask, utf-8, python-2.x, hebrew

I'm trying to store Hebrew in a MySQL table - but I end up seeing question marks.
I'm using a Python flask server.
I believe character sets and collation are set correctly (here is the output for running 'show create table':

> CREATE TABLE `some_table` (`some_field` varchar(128) COLLATE
>   utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT
>   CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

My SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI is:

> 'mysql://username:password@localhost/database?charset=utf8'

The data which I insert into the table is initially received within a Python view function, and I process it as follows:

```
data = request.get_json() 
some_field = data['some_field'].encode('utf-8')
```

I then insert the "some_field" object into the some_field column.

Note: When I try printing the some_field variable to the Python console I also see a gibberish string, but I assume that's because the console itself can't display Hebrew (not sure if this is causing the problem)...

Comment: "I assume that's because the console itself can't display Hebrew" - so don't print the string, print the representation: `':'.join(hex(ord(x))[2:] for x in some_field)` and see if the variable contains what you think it should, and in correct encoding. Also, please tag the post with [tag:python2] or [tag:python3], as it's very relevant when talking about encodings. Also, check whether your web page is in correct encoding as well.

Comment: @Amadan I printed that and got "5e9:5dc:5d5:5dd", which is correct. It's Python2, thanks for pointing that out. The outgoing web request has its encoding set to utf-8. And... using utf8mb4 in the connection string doesn't work either, it causes an error :/

Comment: You got `5e9:5dc:5d5:5dd` before inserting into the database? What did you get after reading from the database? How do you insert? And how do you retrieve?

Comment: @Amadan I read in the incoming data as "data = request.get_json()". When I do "print data", I see {u'some_field': u'\u05e9\u05dc\u05d5\u05dd'}. However, If I try "print data['some_field']" I see gibberish. I insert the data using SQLALCHEMY, I've tried inserting data['some_field'] directly, as well as inserting it after applying decode('utf-8) and/or encode('utf-8')

Comment: Btw, when I try decode('utf-8') I get the error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: You didn't say, what do you get when you take the data out of the database? (hex dump, so we don't get stuck guessing gibberish :) )

Comment: Wow, that was a good question, and I wish I had checked that sooner. It turns out that data is being stored as unicode... it's just that the command line renders everything as question marks. This solved the problem for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When I eventually tried rendering the data directly (rather than just staring it in my mysql console), it turns out that it was stored correctly as unicode. Thank you @Amadan

Answer (score 0):

Don't use encode or decode.  Stick with UTF-8, not Unicode.  I predict you will be unhappy with Unicode in the long run.  See "question mark" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for discussion of likely causes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MySQLdb with Flask (python), and encountered exactly the same (Hebrew from DB appears as question marks *?????*)

solved it with these steps:

1. [[link]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-syntax.html) - Change character sets for each of the levels: DB, Table and Column!
2. [[link]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html) - SET NAMES 'utf8';
3. **This is what I think made the difference:** [[link]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) MySQLdB connection arguments (char set).
   This is what my (python) connection string looks like now:

   ```
   db = MySQLdb.connect(host="username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com",  # your host
                        user="username",  # username
                        passwd="yourpassword",  # password
                        db="db(schema)name", # name of the database
                        charset="utf8",
                        use_unicode=True)
   ```

Notice the *charset* and *use_unicode* although I put the default values, this change solved the problem.

I am not sure if all the previous steps and both arguments were necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `collation='utf8_bin'` to the column definition.
for example, at models.py :

```
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    full_name = db.Column(db.String(80, collation='utf8_bin'), unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
```